# Surface whose points can all be connected by straight lines contained in the surface

Tags: polygons, geometry

I don't know the mathematical term used to define a surface whose points can all be connected by staright lines contained in the surface vs cannot all be connected by straight lines contained in the surface.

My field of expertise is Computational Aerodynamics, and I'm trying to prove that a wing with a delta wing needs to be treated way differently than in the case of a sweptback wing.

This image illustrates some wings planforms. **Compare all of them to the** **Sweptback wing**. Forget about the fuselage and assume the wing is in a plane.
Is there any mathematical term used for this? I can't find the answer on the internet.

[image: Some_Wing_Planforms]

Comment: by "connected by straight line" do you mean "can be connected by a straight line contained in surface"? Then does this mean you are considering flat surfaces? if so then the term you are looking for may be "convexity"

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convex.html

Comment: How easy. I actually used those concepts in elementary maths at school but forgot them, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a [Convex set?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set).  It requires that the line segment connecting any two points of the set be contained in the set.

Comment: Hey Ross, that's the term I think I'm looking for. Other user suggested "Developable surface". What about that?

Comment: I see that.  Did you read the definition he linked to?  Both could be correct.  Convex focuses on the outline of the wing, imagining that the wing surface is in a plane, as you said,  The line between the wingtips on the swept wing goes outside the planform, so the swept wing is not convex.  Developable focuses on the profile of the top of the wing and says the wing does not bend along its length.

Comment: Cool, as the wing is in a plane (as stated in the question) the proper definition is Convex wing vs Concave wing. So I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try "developable surface".https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface
(Apparently that was not enough characters.)

Comment: Can I use concave/convex also? Which of both terms (concave/convex VS Developable surface) is more relevant/precise here? We assume the wings have no dihedral angle so they are contained in a plane. What if the had dihedral? Would these terms hold? Thanks!